# Is there any way for me to avoid uploading sensitive files in this situation?

Tags: security, windows-10, sftp, privacy, winscp

I will soon launch a website. It will be entirely static on the webserver (just HTML files and SVGs and such), which are dynamically generated on my PC. They will be generated every fifteen minutes or so and then synced via SFTP to the webserver using WinSCP (because FileZilla doesn't support scripting/automation).

I use this WinSCP command:

```
synchronize remote "C:\sync dir" "/www_root"
```

According to the WinSCP manual, it means that it makes sure that the remote side is identical to the local side. That is, whatever files are in the local dir will end up in the remote (webserver) dir. I can't find any option to "always exclude JPGs" or anything like that.

My own control script, which runs the WinSCP sync command, calculates the hash for the local dir before it runs the WinSCP sync command. After it's run, it again calculates the hash and compares it with the first. If it's different, that means that something has changed in the dir between it starting to sync and finishing to sync. It notifies me if this happens, but of course, it's too late at that point.

Before my script runs the WinSCP sync command, a general check of the dir is performed, making sure that only the appropriate files are in it. For example, it stops everything and doesn't run the sync command if it detects a JPG file anywhere in it.

The problem is that, it could be that I accidentally move or copy an image (or any kind of) file into the local dir, when it has started to sync but isn't finished syncing yet. If that happens, which is quite possible if it has to do this process every 15 minutes all day long, every day, depending on how the WinSCP developers implemented that feature, my private file will end up on the webserver!

While it's unlikely that any visitor to my website will ever know, the webserver host might very well be logging and storing everything. And even if they don't, I just don't want this to ever happen. It makes my skin crawl thinking about it.

Of course, I won't have any "favorites" or other bookmarks to that upload dir in my File Explorer (which would make this issue much more likely to occur), but it's still *possible* that it could happen, and it makes me feel very paranoid.

I have many times in the past found mystery files (and shortcuts) in dirs which I don't remember putting there, but which end up being explained by me accidentally moving the mouse cursor while clicking or holding down the mouse button, etc. It actually does happen, and Windows normally doesn't ask you but just performs the file move/copy operation instantly and very subtly.

As far as I know, there is no (sane) way to enable some sort of "special treatment" per-directory, such as "make this specific dir read-only unless you send this password with it" or something. There's tons of weird stuff in Windows, but I hope to avoid setting all kinds of weird permissions and audit options, if it can be done in a saner way which I just haven't thought of.

Please note: No, I can't put the actual logic on the webserver. And I can't use a VM. And I can't use Docker. There are very important reasons for why I can't do these things. I need it to be done in this manner because of complicated reasons. It's got a lot to do with security. Yes, it is super ironic that I'm talking about security yet run Windows, etc. Not all Windows users are the same. My Windows doesn't in almost any way resemble Windows. I don't like Windows myself. It's a complicated world and in my situation, it has to be done like this.

Comment: Am I really seeing no less than two downvotes? Surreal...

Comment: Your post contains a ton of information that is completely irrelevant to the core of your question, and doesn’t really conform to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: It’s also not at all clear how you arrived at the idea that running some code on a server or running something in a Docker container or a Virtual Machine automatically introduces such huge security holes that it’s completely off the table...

Comment: Finally what you’re describing is largely what seems to be user error - can you elaborate on how often the dragging of files occurs for you that it’s a material concern that an otherwise “private” file of yours would end up in another folder inadvertently?

Comment: @esqew I very carefully avoided including anything irrelevant. Did you actually read it?

Comment: @esqew Why question me instead of helping?

Comment: I certainly read your question, and resent any implication to the contrary. Can you share how exactly your last paragraph is at all relevant aside from the stipulation that you cannot use a server for this task? To me, it reads as a rant disguised as part of your question, which runs counter to Stack Overflow’s quality guidelines.

Comment: To your second question - my comments are simply to help myself and others in the community ultimately help *you*. Clarifications can uncover root causes and previously untested scenarios with your solution design; comments regarding your question itself are largely meant to help enforce Stack Overflow’s quality standards and ensure that questions here are of use to you as well as to future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP’s `synchronize` command has a flag to enforce a file mask, aptly named `-filemask`:

> `-filemask=<mask>`
>
> Sets [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

WinSCP can help you build said mask with its built-in [File Mask Dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_editmask) feature. Pass the result of this utility to your script to include and exclude files based on their type or other criteria from the synchronization.

Comment: This is helpful. I somehow missed that, probably because I was looking for "exclude" or such keywords. Thanks. It sounds like this will do the trick.